# How to get Scroll to work with a Vertically oriented Hub Control Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm building a WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 applicaiton. I want to use a vertical hub control with three hub sections. But, vertical scrolling for the hub control doesn't seem to work even after enabling all the necessary scrollviewer properties on the hub. How do I enable the vertical scrolling?

Here is my Hub Control

```
<Hub Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True">
    <HubSection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="HELLO 1" FontSize="50" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="HELLO 2" FontSize="50" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="HELLO 3" FontSize="50" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Hub is designed to be used with Orientation=”horizontal” ONLY. Do not use it in Orientation=”vertical”.

Found at [Windows blogs post](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps/)

As well as

> The hub control's behavior and rendering is supported in portrait orientation only.

at [MSDN WP8.1 Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn596112.aspx)